# session start() creates new session file entry in every request

Tags: php, session

i am using angular 2 to make a cross origin(angular 2 files are located localhost and api files in a remote server) http post request to user.php file. User.php uses session to determine the state of the user, the problem is that session_start() creates a new session file entry in /tmp folder.

php.ini

```
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length  32  32
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.lazy_write  On  On
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /tmp    /tmp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS   PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_strict_mode Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

user.php

```
<?php

session_start();

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://votingsystem.gr:4200');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Type, Authorization');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

require_once 'utilities/constants.php';
// require_once 'utilities/jwt.php';
// print_r($_SESSION['id']);
// session_save_path('/tmp');
if (empty($_SESSION)) {
    $response['empty session'] = 'empty session';
} else {
    $response['not empty session'] = 'not empty( session)';
}

if (file_get_contents('php://input') != null) {

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    // $response['action'] = $data->action;
    if ($data->action != null && !empty($data->action)) {
        // $jwt = new JWT();

        if ($data->action === 'login_admin') {
            // $_SESSION['id'] = 10;
            $_SESSION['username'] = 'admin';
            // $response['id'] = $_SESSION['id'];
            $response['username'] = $_SESSION['username'];
        } else if ($data->action === 'login_user') {
            //for mobile users
        } else if ($data->action === 'check_admin_state') {
            // $response['id'] = $_SESSION['username'];
            if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
                $response['code'] = STATUS_OK;
                $response['desc'] = 'User authorized.';
            } else {
                // $response['session'] = $_SESSION;
                $response['code'] = ERROR_UNAUTHORIZED_USER;
                $response['desc'] = 'User unathorized.';
            }
        } else {

        }
        // $response['code'] = STATUS_OK;
    } else {
        $response['code'] = ERROR_INVALID_ACTION;
        $response['desc'] = 'Invalid action.';
    }
    // $response['session'] = $_SESSION;
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, after hours of digging i figured it out. The problem is that on cross origin requests cookie is not sent to the server, so my angular code did not sent it. I changed this

angular 2 code for those who are interested:

```
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });

    let body = { action: 'login_admin', username: 'test', password: 'password' };

    return this.http.post('url',
            JSON.stringify(body), options)
        .map(this.success)
        .catch(this.error);
```

and i added

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

in user.php file and session_start() does not anymore creates new file entries, it is working like expected.

Comment: Did you end up able to use the session cookie to handle your authentication? I am having the same exact issue, but your fix doesn't work for me.